# SQL datetime into date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure the way to break the datetime field  become 2 columns weekday and time

```
ContactDate
2019-07-09 09:15:12.000
```

My query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(contactdate, 'ddd') AS Result FROM contact
```

And the outcome only week date but no time. How do we get the time? Thank you.

```
Result
Tue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `DATENAME` and `CONVERT`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(3),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,ContactDate)),
       CONVERT(time(3),ContactDate)
FROM dbo.Contact;
```

I recommend against `FORMAT`. Although it's a useful function, it is significantly slower than other functions; especially when dealing with large sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(contactdate as time) [time]
```